# Regex match literal containing substring anywhere in input

Tags: regex

I'm a little bit confused with regular expressions, while I'm trying to match literal(string) in input, but the input can have substring in wanted literal.

For better understanding:

regex `foobar`

input `this is fooXbar`

wanted match `fooXbar`

Basically the question is, if it is possible to specify 'X' can be anywhere in input string or if I have to do this:

ugly regex: `fX?oX?oX?bX?aX?r`

Comment: No there is no way. Remove all X before.

Comment: What implementation of regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to list `X?` explicitly.

Also note that you did not include `X?` after `r`, which means that `X?` does not apply to all positions.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the X? using other tools, for example

```
 grep -oE "$(echo foobar | sed 's/./&X?/g')" file
```

will match fooXbar and other versions